# GET request works with Postman but why doesn't it work with ReactJS fetch?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, fetch, postman

When I make a GET request on Postman, it successfully makes the GET request:

[image]
But when I do a GET fetch in ReactJS:

```
var data = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'vin': 'TESTVIN1234567890'
}

var myInit = {
  method: 'GET',
  mode: 'no-cors',
  header: data,
};

fetch('http://www.localhost:8080/ota/upload/config/', myInit)
  .then(result=>result.json())
  .then(body=>{
      console.log(body)
  });
```

I get the following error (with Uncaught SyntaxError pointing to the line : `.then(result=>result.json())`):

[image]

So I tested to see if fetch is correct with http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts and it fetches correctly.

What could be the issue? Anything I am missing?

**EDIT**

I tried the following but got `'Network response was not ok.` and logged the following in EDIT 2:

```
  fetch('http://www.localhost:8080/ota/upload/config/', myInit).then(function(response) {
    if(response.ok) {
      response.blob().then(function(myBlob) {
        var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
        console.log(objectURL)
      });
    } else {
      console.log('Network response was not ok.');
    }
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
  });
```

**EDIT 2 - ADDITIONAL INFO**

[image]

Comment: it's `headers` not `header`

Comment: @azium Tried but didn't work unfortunately...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend looking at the `fetch` [API documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) - but I have some general advice:

1) I usually include error handling whenever fetching from an API, because you don't have enough information to know exaclty why the request failed. The docs have a decent example:

```
fetch('flowers.jpg').then(function(response) {
  if(response.ok) {
    response.blob().then(function(myBlob) {
      var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
      myImage.src = objectURL;
    });
  } else {
    console.log('Network response was not ok.');
  }
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
});
```

2. This is an educated guess, but based on the limited information I gathered from the error message, you're using `HMR` -  which does modify some code - specifically related to how state is propagated within components.

So first I'd rec. console logging the `error.message` using the documentation as a guide (prob `catch`) - and if you haven't solved the problem, then I think we need more context (like where is this inrelation to a component? how are you propagating the state? etc.)

> edit: or maybe it's just a typo - but still - error handling is good and there's a few 'gotchas' with using HMR

Comment: Tried the error handling but got the following: `GET http://www.localhost:8080/ota/upload/config/ 415 ()` and `Network response was not ok.`. And as for the second suggestion, the fetch to another URL but in exactly the same way worked, so I would assume HMR is fine and so far hasn't put any troubles. What could be the issue?

Comment: Logged the response from the server as well. Put it up on the original post.

Comment: just checking to see if you've received my message. please let me know

Answer (score 0):

instead of using localhost use Ip address

```
fetch('SYSTEM_IP_ADDRESS:8080/ota/upload/config/', myInit)
  .then(result=>result.json())
  .then(body=>{
  console.log(body)
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably `=>` is not supported by the browser you're testing this on, even though Chrome supports it. You should replace your arrow functions with regular functions and see if everything works now.

This is the list of browsers that support it:

[image: list]

[source](http://caniuse.com/#search=arrow)

If that's the case, you can use Babel and/or Webpack to transpile.

Comment: I am already using Babel and Webpack but still get that error